# Grid.Refresh() no funciona en grid de atributos con conditions Android

Tags: genexus

GX 17 U9, Android, en un SDPanel, tengo un grid de attributos, por ejemplo AttCodigo y AttDescripción.
Fuera del Grid, en el mismo SDPanel, agrego una variable &AttCodigo basada en AttCodigo, y en las conditions de la grid:

```
AttCodigo = &AttCodigo when not &AttCodigo.IsEmpty()
```

Agrego un botón que sea "Actualizar Grilla", que en el .Tap haga

```
Grid.Refresh()
```

En ejecución, cuando se hace Tap en el botón, la grilla no se actualiza con la condition.
He probado esto con múltiples atributos y multiples conditions, también poniendo el Grid.Refresh()
en el .ControlValueChanged de &AttCodigo.

¿Es una limitación de Genexus o un error que no funcione el Grid.Refresh()?

Comment: Prueba poniendo la variable &AttCodigo en la parm del Panel. Como el evento refresh es un evento server-side no le debe estar llegando el nuevo valor de la variable al data provider del refresh del grid.

Comment: Impecable, con eso funciona, ¡muchas gracias!